# What causes inbox notifications to expand to fewer notifications?

Tags: support, notifications, global-inbox

I had a notification on my mobile of 6 inbox notifications, and both on it and PC, it showed 6. However, when I clicked on it, it expanded to...3 notifications.

[image: 6 inbox notifications]

Perhaps spam answers and comments were shown in the amount of notifications, but not when expanded? I recently has a question that became a "Hot Network Question" and it attracted spam replies.

Comment: I disagree that this is a dupe, though tags are partly to blame here.  This question seems to be asking why it happens, while the other argues that it shouldn't.

Comment: But the linked question provides the answer: "After looking into the notifications, it appears that what happened is that the notification list merged multiple comment notifications into a single notification."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've seen this happen when there are multiple new comments on the same post -- the counter has the correct total, but the expansion lists each post only once.

It can also happen if the things you were being notified of were deleted, though *usually* the number syncs up eventually.

Comment: Can you put this answer on the duplicate question? The dupe has no answers.

Comment: @Zackary I'm not sure this is actually a dupe.  Your questions asks why it happened; the other questions says it happens, suggests a reason (overlapping my answer), and then argues that it shouldn't.  I think your question should be [tag:support] and not marked as a dupe.